# (Concisely/efficiently) ignoring lone characters when eliminating initials in (multiple) names

Tags: regex, r, data.table

I'm trying to strip initials from ~10 million names, but am looking for an efficient/concise way to build in an exception for names made up of single characters.

For example:

```
dt<-data.table(fnm=c("audrey e","joe buck","m","w c"),
               lnm=c("claire","b","nop","fields"))
```

If I just do:

```
nm<-c("fnm","lnm")
dt[,paste0("str_",nm):=lapply(.SD,function(x)gsub("\\s|\\b[a-z]\\b","",x)),
   .SDcols=nm]; rm(nm)
```

`"m"`, `"b"` and `"w c"` get deleted, which causes me trouble later:

```
        fnm    lnm str_fnm str_lnm
1: audrey e claire  audrey  claire
2: joe buck      b joebuck        
3:        m    nop             nop
4:      w c fields          fields
```

A wordy alternative would be to explode the lines of code necessary:

```
dt[gsub("\\s","",str_fnm)=="",str_fnm:=fnm]
dt[gsub("\\s","",str_lnm)=="",str_lnm:=lnm]
```

In addition to being long-winded, this seems somewhat inefficient because I still need to do vector comparison.

Basically, what I need is a way to build the single character exception into the regex itself; is there a way to do this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: @akrun that will eliminate first and last letters as well, but I think you're on to something

Comment: I guess I meant `dt[,paste0("str_",nm):= lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub(' \\b[a-z]\\b|\\b[a-z]\\b ', '', x))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing some detail, but why not simply:

```
sub("( [a-z])+$|^([a-z] )+", "", x)
```

---

Seems like the problem is more complex and is probably not worth trying to solve using a regex. So just fix it afterwards:

```
for (x in nm) dt[get(paste0('str_', x)) == "", paste0('str_', x) := get(x)]
```

Comment: My example wasn't robust enough, as this would miss, e.g. `"w c fields"`

Comment: @MichaelChirico that's very easy to account for - see edit

Comment: This missed `"jo ann a"` (output: `"joann a"`); if we simply replace `sub` by `gsub` we miss `"dianne a wilson"` (output: `"dianneawilson"`)

Comment: "jo ann a" seems to work correctly (becomes "jo ann"), and while it's easy to add another clause to handle your second case, @akrun's comment works much better than this answer. If you however also want to keep "w c" as-is, then I actually don't have a solution for you aside from basically what you have in OP.

Comment: I'm thinking so as well, with a `lapply`  to do the three cases in a line.

Comment: Thanks for this, with so many strings it's easy to miss special cases I hadn't noticed before.